# Understanding convergence in probability, why do we write $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon$) instead of $P(|X_n-X|<\epsilon$)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

The definition states :
a sequence ${X_n}$ of random variables converges in probability towards the random variable $X$ if for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ : $\lim_{n\to \infty}Pr(|X_n-X|\gt \epsilon)=0$\

Why can't we write $\lim_{n\to \infty}Pr(|X_n-X|\lt \epsilon)=0$ knowing that we want the probability of $X_n-X$ to be $0$  with a large enough $n$?

Comment: You want the probability that $X_n$ is quite different from $X$, which is measured by $P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon)$ to get smaller and smaller as $n$ grows.

Comment: "$\lim_{n\to \infty}Pr(|X_n-X|\lt \epsilon)=0$ knowing that we want the probability of $X_n-X$ to be $0$  with a large enough $n$" is probably not quite what you are trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you mean for "they go for first one"? It depends which book you are reading. This is from Casella Berger, one of the most reputable source and, as you can see, both definitions are given

[image]

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]=0$$

is the same as writing

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}[|X_n-X|\leq \epsilon]=1$$

Comment: Yeah, but why do we go for the first one? I feel like the second writing is less ambiguous. All the definitions I encountered use the first expression, is there a reason for that?

Comment: @Hijaw : they are exactly the same. You can use the one you prefer for your calculation. Often I prefer the second one too....

Comment: I get that they are the same, I just didn't get why would they go for first one when defining convergence in probability.

Comment: As far as I know, the reason for why the first definition is usually given, is because it generalizes well to the case where the measure is not finite, whereas the other does not.